# GStreamer DeadLock

Tags: gstreamer, deadlock

Currently I am working on an application using gstreamer 1.0, this application should to open a stream over rtsp, all work fine if no problem is detected on stream. But when arrived an ERROR or EOS message and I try to call:
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL)

over the pipeline, this call block the thread and nothing happen.

Could anyone help me with this issue on GStreamer.?

Comment: set the rtsp element to expect a EOS when it arrives by calling gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_eos_shutdown () and setting it to true - see the gstreamer docs for details on this function

Comment: Hello Samer, thanks for your answer. But the problem here is that I am not stream the video. I am opening the stream of a ip camera using a  "pipeline" with "uridecodebin"  inside it

Comment: Without exact pipeline or debug messages, it's hard to tell what's wrong.  Have you tried https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding We should not call `gst_element_set_state()` in any of the `gstreamer` thread. It may cause deadlock.